# Initializing data.frames()

Tags: r

Is there a quick way to initialize an empty data frame? If you know what the dimensions will be? For example:

Suppose I would like a blank data frame that has 100 rows and 10:

```
x <- data.frame(1:100,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
dim(x) ## that's right
```

But suppose I want something like 300 columns? How do I quickly initialize columns in a data.frame?

```
x <- data.frame(1:100,2,3,4,5 ....) ## *cries*
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi marking duplicates, 5 years later. Bravo

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
> df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 300, nrow = 100))
> dim(df)
[1] 100 300
```

Comment: How do I add column names for only some columns?

Comment: `colnames(df) = paste0("a", 1:300)`

Comment: @MarkBower +1 I would generally use `names()` for a data frame, however.

Answer (score 36):

I always just convert a matrix:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 10))
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Looks like Gavin beat you to the type :P

Comment: @Brandon actually @Matt beat me to it. I blame adding the `dim(df)` output for that ;-)

Comment: Hmm, you proved the dimensions and actually used the number of columns specified in the question; what counts more toward bestfulness?  It's probably unwise to contribute toward my ability to edit other people's posts, anyway...